# Portable, machine-readable way to store column names from several CSV files

Tags: python, bash, data-structures

Right now I have a folder with several comma-separated data files and I would like to extract their column names to store in some kind of index for later reference. This data will be used by multiple people on both Mac and Windows machines (so newlines could pose a problem), in both R and Python.

Ideally, I'd like to write or use a script that takes a regex as an argument and returns a list of file names that contain that column name. E.g. I could write, say, `cl col 'Years at'` and return all of the files with a column containing the text `Years at`, or `cl file 'Academic Data'` and return all of the column names in that file.

I only have a few files and only a few columns in each, but I would like to be able to scale this up to situations where I have a large number of files, and/or where each file has a large number of columns.

Is there a "best practice" in this situation? Is there a "right way" to store this data? I'm thinking about JSON, but the only way I can think of getting it into JSON format would be by manually `echo`ing all the braces and newlines, which would be ugly. And I'd have no idea how to get the data back out.

---

This is my current solution:

```
find . -iname "*.csv" | while read f; do
    echo -e "$f\n$(tr "\r" "\n" < "$f" | head -n1)\n" >> column_index.txt
done
```

which produces:

```
./File 1.csv
column 1, column 2, column 3

./File 2.csv
column 1, column 2, column 3
```

There are two problems with it: 1) it's in bash, so a Windows user can't use it without Cygwin 2) the output is readable but hard to parse safely. Problem 2 is the point of the question. But I'll be happy to hear suggestions that also tackle Problem 1 somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python.Pandas to manipulate CSV files.

```
df= pd.read_csv(name)
print df.columns # will print all the columns,
```

Check this [tutorial for more details](http://www.bearrelroll.com/2013/05/python-pandas-tutorial/)

I would suggest:

- Loop in all the csv files, store columns and their original files.
- Store these informational on another csv files (or json).
- Write a python script that does the research inside this csv, so any win/mac user can use it.

Comment: Thanks for the outline. However I'd rather not load the entire data set just to read the first row... any reason not to use `readline().split(',')`?